# How do you use ASWebAuthenticationSession, native app, https: redirect required?

Tags: ios, swift, aswebauthenticationsession

I'm using ASWebAuthenticationSession for OAuth and all works well when I can use my custom scheme.  However, when I try it with a service that requires a protocol in the redirect url "https://myapp.com/auth", I just see "cannot find server..." after I do the authorization steps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your private scheme instead of `https` which is handled by Safari.

1. Set your project to handle your scheme: `com.my.app` (for example)
2. Init session for you scheme: `let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: "com.my.app://", completionHandler: completion)`

Further readings:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.1

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that.  The OAuth server responds with "invalid url"

Comment: Do you have an access to setting for your application on oauth server? You need to change redirect uri if possible. If no, ask technical support to allow native application schemes and send them RFC8252.

Comment: I do have access.  I set the URI to match.  I access another server and my app has no problem with that one.

Comment: The server accepts "myapp.com" as the URI, but if I don't include "https://" when I request the auth code, it responds with an invalid URI.  If I include it, Safari says it can't find the server.  The service I'm trying to connect to is Ecobee... this shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: How do you init step 2 in obj-c?

Comment: @CogitoErgoBibo have you solved the problem? I'm experiencing a similar problem with Amazon Alexa.